# Map with JavaPairRDD with List values

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to iterator over a JavaPairedRDD with List value. I want to iterate over each entries, but it seems like I am always iterating over all the elements in the list of values. For instance, I have a pairedRDD like this.

```
[(0,[date, date, date]), (1,[str, str, str]), (2,[str, str, str]), (3,[str, int, str]), (4,[int, int, int]), (5,[float, float, int]), (6,[float, float, float])]
```

And I want to extract most common element in values for each entries of Pair. So for this one, I want

```
[date, str, str, str, int, float, float]
```

How do I do this? I will list few attempts I tried, but they are iterating over all the elements in the value. I defined a function that returns most common element for list and tried this:

```
JavaRDD<String> resultrdd = pair_rdd.map(e -> mostCommon(e._2));
```

and this

```
JavaRDD<String> result = pair_rdd.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Integer, List<String>>, String>(){

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> call(Tuple2<Integer, List<String>> t) throws Exception {
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            List<String> type = t._2;
            result.add(mostCommon(type));
            return result.iterator();
        }

});
```

All resulting in all the elements in the list, thus

```
[date, str, str, str, int, float, float,date, str, int, str, int, float, float,date, str, str, str, int, int, float]
```

I think e._2 is not referring to the whole list, but each elements of the list. Any help?

Edit : Here is my mostcommon method. If there is "None", it just prefers the other type.

```
public static <String> String mostCommon(List<String> list) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String t : list) {
        Integer val = map.get(t);
        map.put(t, val == null ? 1 : val + 1);
    }

    Entry<String, Integer> max = null;

    for (Entry<String, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getKey().equals("None")==false) {
            if (max == null || e.getValue() > max.getValue())
                max = e;
        }
    }
    if(max==null) {
        return (String) "None";
    }else {
        return max.getKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `map`, not `flatMap`. You're transforming tuples into single elements, not flattening nested lists

And you just need to `return mostCommon(t._2)`, assuming that returns a single string

> I think e._2 is not referring to the whole list,

It has to be the whole list. Otherwise, this doesn't compile

```
List<String> type = t._2;
```

Your first 7 elements are correct, so I think you have extra data in your RDD

Comment: first 7 is right, but if you look at the following entries, they are different from the first ones. date, str, int, str, int, float, float. -- this is the next seven elements. And another reason why I think so -- if I print the length of the incoming rdd, it is 7, but the resulting rdd is 21. I think it is going through each element.

Comment: First one looks correct, yes. Not clear what your mostCommon function looks like or what it  returns.